# c++: data on stack without initializing it

Tags: c++, memory

I want to create an adapter that uses a function of the signature `void convert(void* input, T* out, int* ok)` where T is overloaded to whatever type, and `ok` indicated whether an error occurred (these functions are provided and I cannot change their body). A snippet of the functionality inside the template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T convert_adapter(void* input){
    T result;
    int ok = 1;
    convert(input, &result, &ok);
    if (!ok)
        throw Exception("error during conversion");
    return result;
}
```

This works well enough for types like int and simple structs but fails on more complex classes and structs without a default constructor since `result` can't be default initialized in the first line. Thing is, if an error occurs in `convert`, I don't use `result`, and if an error doesn't occur, `convert` will assign to `result` an initialized value on its own (`*out = {...}`), so I never need to actually initialize `result` myself.

How can I provide `convert` with a pointer to uninitialized data to the appropriate type? I'm aware I could probably do this with a `char[sizeof(T)]`, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

**EDIT: I see now this problem goes against some basic concepts of C++, I will try to talk with the provider of `convert` to find a solution. I will leave this question up for posterity.**

Comment: `convert` doesn't initialize, it assigns. And using `char[sizeof(T)]` without changing `convert` to initialize instead of assign won't end well.

Comment: What you are doing will almost definitely be undefined behaviour. This sort of casting from memory is xraying objects and may not even work with POD types. It is called [type punning](https://adriann.github.io/undefined_behavior.html) and it breaks c++ *strict aliasing rules*.

Comment: What are the *existing* use cases for `convert()` for the types that don't support a default constructor?     For example, if `convert(input, &some_foo, int *ok)` is  called, where `some_foo` is of type `Foo`, how is `some_foo` initialised?   With that information, you will probably be able to specify a suitable specialisation of `convert_adapter<Foo>()`.   Without that information, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: @Peter, for example, class `Point` that takes two `int`s. `convert` could, for example, do: `*out = {3,4};`

Comment: Are you allowed to *read* the source code of `convert`? If so, post it. If not, you need to read the *documentation*. If the authors of `convert` intended it to be usable with such classes, they would have provided guidelines in the documentation. It is absolutely impossible to write `convert` that work with *all* classes, so the authors would have needed to pick some fixed set of types `convert` is able to work with, and describe it in the documentation.

Comment: @bentheiii - that's not what I requested.   If there are use cases for `convert()` involving classes without a default constructor, those use cases will include some information about how the object is created.

Comment: Your function will also not work with C-style arrays, and not because of a fault of `convert`. The obvious solution is to drop the idea of wrapping `convert`, or at least to drop the idea of giving the wrapper a radically different interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(*out = {...})` this does not initialize.

Assignment and initialization are not the same thing.  Assigning to uninitialized data is UB in the cases you seek to optimize.

You can placement new to initialize, but as you cannot change the body of convert this is not permitted.

Comment: Yes, but assigning an initialized value of the same type behaves as initialization, no? Unless the type overloads the assignment operator.

Comment: Fair enough. I wish there was some way to assign without destructing or declare without initializing, but I see I approached this problem with the wrong mindset.

Comment: @benth no it does not.  Assigning by default does element wise assign.  If recursively there are no overloads of assignment, then your data is probably pod, and constructing it was probably free in the first case.  See the rule of three(five(zero)).

Comment: @bentheiii And you can construct-into-memory address, and create memory on the stack for objects without an object there.  But you said you cannot change the function that does the assignment, so you are out of luck: it assigns, and assignment demands there already is an object there.

Answer (score 0):

Since `result` is returned anyways, why not change the signature of `convert_adapter`? You could have it as out-parameter instead of return value:

```
template<typename T>
convert_adapter(void* input, T* result){
    int ok = 1;
    convert(input, result, &ok);
    if (!ok)
        throw Exception("error during conversion");
    return;
}
```

This way you can initialize `result` outside of `convert_adapter` where you can use non-default constructors. A variable of type `T` has to exist where you call `convert_adapter` anyway since you probably want to assign the result to something.

```
T result(non,default,contructor,parameter,values);
//result = convert_adapter(input); // old
convert_adapter(input, &result); // new
```